# AWS create multiple ec2 instances

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, multiple-instances

In this oportunity I came to you because I have a doubt, I've been reading the AWS APIs documentation about create instance dynamically in node js,  I understand every steps of they example code, and I even tried it and runned it. My question is, is there an API or WAY provied by AWS to create multiples instances in differents regions?

I'm thinking to do it by my own, but I wanna know if there is an efficent way already developed to do this.

Thank you so much before hand.

Comment: you need to  be more specific about what do you want by to achieve..  if you can create one instance, you can simply repeat the process to create multiple instances. Or you could use autoscaling group or ec2 fleet to create whole set of instances. but without more specific question it's difficult to guess what answer would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All AWS API calls are made to a **single region**.

Therefore, if you wish to launch resources in multiple regions, you will need to **send commands to each region individually**.

An exception to this are **global services** (IAM, CloudFront, Route 53, WAF).

Also, [AWS CloudFormation StackSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html) can **launch resources in multiple regions**:

[image: AWS CloudFormation StackSets]